# JQuery SlideDown on program startup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was thinking, would it be possible to set an object to SlideDown on startup?
I already know how to set it as SlideUp using

display:none

I was wondering if the other way around was possible.

Thanks!
Nico :D

Comment: please elaborate your question. try to put your code so that we can help you..

Comment: @SrikanthKshatriy His question was pretty clear. He wants an element that makes a slidedown animation as soon as the page/program is done loading by using JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#your_element').hide();
    $('#your_element').slideDown();
});
```

Will make your element slide down as soon as the document is done loading (aka: program startup).

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Amx8/1/) for a live demo.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the element onload and then slidedown.

```
$(function(){
   $('#eleToSlide').hide();
   $('#eleToSlide').slideDown();
});
```

or just

```
$(function(){
   $('#eleToSlide').slideDown();
});
```

if the element is hidden with css already